# Suppose that $x$ and $y$ satisfy $\frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{3} = 1$. Prove that $x^2 + y^2 > 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-verification

Ok , i tried to prove this via Contrapositive setting $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$. After doing some algebra i have arrived at $x \le \sqrt{-y^2}$. I'm fairly sure this isn't right. I also solved for x and y in equation one hoping this would somehow lead me to a conclusion, it didn't.

Comment: Where did the $1$ disappear?

Comment: I re wrote the right hand side as sqrt(1) - sqrt(-y^2) so the sqrt(1) just becomes 1. Hence sqrt(-y^2) remains?

Comment: If it were $x\le\sqrt{1-y^2}$, would make more sense..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the above answers are correct, there's no need for anything as complicated as what's been posted so far. Given the (unstated) assumption that $x$ and $y$ are both real numbers, then $x^2\geq0$ and likewise $y^2\geq0$. Now assume provisionally that $x=y=1$. Then $\frac{x}2 +\frac{y}3=\frac{5}6$, which is less than $1$. So at least one of the two variables must be greater than $1$, and likewise its square must be greater than $1$. Since we already know that the square of the other variable must be at least $0$, it follows that the sum $x^2 + y^2$  must be greater than $1+0$ $(=1)$.

Answer (score 4):

Your line is, after multiplying by 6 and moving things to the left, $3x+2y-6=0$, whose distance to the origin is $|-6|/\sqrt{3^2+2^2}=6/\sqrt{13}\approx 1.6641.$

See [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) for the distance from point to line formula, with several proofs of it.

Added: to proceed via the contrapositive, assume in fact that $x^2+y^2 \le 1$. Then we have $|x|\le 1$ and $|y| \le 1$, from which
$$3x+2y \le 3|x|+2|y| \le 3+2=5,$$
making $3x+2y=6$ not possible.

Comment: I am trying to prove it via the contrapositive method though.

Comment: @Achilles OK I'll think about that.

Comment: Thank you , ill be sure to comment back immediately if i figure it out.

Comment: I see makes good sense now , just one quick question if i may. What allows us to say |x| <= 1 and |y|<= 1?

Comment: @Achilles If $|x|>1$ then also $x^2>1$ so that, since $y^2 \ge 0$, we would have $x^2+y^2>1$ but we are assuming the sum of the squares is at most $1$ in this instance.

Comment: How do we know that |x| > 1 for sure here? Also , i don't see where Y^2 >= to 0 is coming from. Sorry , i'm not trying to be bothersome.

Comment: @Achilles We want to derive each of $|x|\le 1$ and $|y| \le 1$ from the assumption that $x^2+y^2\le 1.$ We do this proof by contradiction, and if the two absolute values of $x,y$ are not *both* less or equal to 1, then one of them, say $x$ without loss of generality, must be such that $|x|>1$. But this leads to a contradiction as in previous comment. [also $y^2\ge 0$ for any real number $y$ by considering positive and negative $y$.]

Comment: Thanks a lot , everything is very clear now. I appreciate the help thanks again coffeemath.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Try the other way: $x/2+y/3=1$, so, $\frac32x+y=3$, yielding $y=3-\frac32 x$. Then compute $x^2+y^2$.

Or, even better: try geometrically: the set of points $(x,y)$ on the plane that satisfy $x/2+y/3=1$ is a line. This line contains $(2,0)$ and $(0,3)$. Draw it and draw also the disk $x^2+y^2<1$.

Comment: Ok, i came up with the y = 3 - 3/2x. Now your just saying sub it in for y and do the algebra?

Comment: yes, that was the first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$ x^2 + (3 - 3/2x)^2 = 9 - 9x + {13\over 4}x^2 = {13\over 4}\left(x^2
- {36\over 13}x + \right)+9= {13\over 4}\left(x^2 - {36\over 13}x + {324\over 169}\right)+ 9 - {13\over 4}\cdot {324\over 169} $$

This expression evaluates to 
$${13\over 4}\left(x^2 - {36\over 13}x + {324\over 169}\right)+ 9 - {81\over 13}
= {13\over 4}\left(x^2 - {18\over 13}\right)^2 + {36\over 13} $$

There is a lower bound of $36/13$, which is larger than 1.

Comment: I see , quite the rigorous proof here, thank you. The After seeing this it shows me the power of the contrapostive method.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the standard coordinate axes with your line. Now consider the triangle formed by the intersection of these axes with the line in the first quadrant. (A right triangle with base length=2 and height=3.)

Now draw a new line from the origin to your line such that the lines are perpendicular. This point of intersection is the closest your line ever gets to the origin, and thus serves as a lower bound for $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Let us use the law of sines on the new triangle we just formed to find the distance $D$:
$$ \frac{\sin\arctan(3/2)}{D} = \frac{\sin\left(\pi/2)\right)}{2}. $$

As was observed by @coffeemath, $D=6/\sqrt{13}\approx 1.6641$.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add variety to the answers, we can prove directly using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$$(x^2+y^2)\left(\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2}\right) \ge \left(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{3}\right)^2$$
Manipulating, we have
$$x^2+y^2 \ge \frac{36}{13}$$
$$x^2 + y^2 > 1$$

Of course, this approach assumes that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is true.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two geometric ways to prove this:

**Method.$(1)$**

Let the line intersect with the x-axis at point $A(2,0)$, and intersect with the y-axis at point $B(0,3)$. Draw the height from  $O$ to the hypotenuse and intersect with $AB$ at $H$, $\Rightarrow OH\perp AB$. So $OH$ is the shortest distance from $O$ to the straight line $AB$.

So we have $OA=2,~OB=3,~AB=\sqrt{13}$. From the triangle area, we have:
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot OA\cdot OB=\frac{1}{2}\cdot AB\cdot OH~~\Rightarrow~~OH=\frac{6}{\sqrt{13}}$$

Because $OH$ is the shortest distance from $O$ to the straight line $AB$, and $OH>1=R$, where the radius of the circle is $R=1$. Therefore, the straight line $AB$ is outside the circle. So for all points on the straight line, which satisfying $\frac{x}2+\frac{y}3=1$, their distances to the origin $O$ are greater than $1$. Namely, $x^2+y^2>1$.

**Method.$(2)$**

Combine two equations:

$$\frac{x}2+\frac{y}3=1,~~~x^2+y^2=1$$

Eliminating $x$ (or eliminating $y$), and we get a quadratic equation, it is easy to show it has no real roots, which means there are no intersecting points or touching points between the straight line and the circle. This means the line is outside the circle. So for all points on the straight line, which satisfying $\frac{x}2+\frac{y}3=1$, their distances to the origin $O$ are greater than $1$. Namely, $x^2+y^2>1$.